# How to fix binding property xaml to code?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use a **binding** to show all categories of a exhibitor, that are stored in a list (ExtendedExhibitor.categories).

I created a **property** in ViewModel to iterate in all categories and print the name of them. From debugging it seems that program doesn't reach property, so maybe I made a mistake in the binding.

Here are the important pieces of code:

**DetailPage.xaml**

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" IsVisible="{Binding DetailPageViewModel.ExtExhSector, Converter={StaticResource StringNullOrEmptyBoolConverter}}">
  <Label Text="Settore: " TextColor="Blue"/>
  <Label Text="{Binding DetailPageViewModel.ExtExhSector}"/>
</StackLayout>
```

**DetailPageViewModel.cs**

```
string extExhSector;
public string ExtExhSector
{
   get
     {
        for (int i = 0; i < ExtendedExhibitor.categories.Count; i++)
                    extExhSector += ExtendedExhibitor.categories[i].ToString();
        return extExhSector;
      }
   set
     {
       extExhSector = value;
       PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ExtExhSector)));
     }
}
```

I'm expecting to see a concatenated string with names of categories.

Now I only see "Settore:    ", with the result of binding that is blank.

You can see the result in the photo:
[image: Result]

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, If  "DetailPageViewModel" is your binding context in that case it would be unneccesary to use DetailPageViewModel.property name instead you can bind them directly {Binding PropertyName}. Also i would suggest doing additional functionality in the gettter and setter of the property, instead try to assign the formatted value to the property while you generate it. Hope it helps

Comment: Are you sure the `Count` is greater than 0 there? I mean, if you put `return "foo"` in the `ExtExhSector` then you still don't see anything?

Comment: @Dilmah if I set the binding context of DetailPage the app crashes. What can I change if the get is not reached from the program? Sorry for the inexperience but I'm new in programming.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I tried return "foo" but the result it's still the same, blank.

Comment: @Andrea How are you assigning the binding context ? can you update code block a bit.

Comment: @Dilmah I assigned now the binding context in **DetailPage.xaml.cs**: `public DetailPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingContext = new DetailPageViewModel();
        }`

Comment: But if I use the binding like that: `{Binding ExtExhSector}` the app crashes.

Comment: @Andrea Can you post the logs from the output window, atleast we can debug what is causing the crash.

Comment: @Dilmah this is the exception: `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.` That is caused by: `BindingContext = new DetailPageViewModel();`

Comment: every time ExtExhSector is called it will modify extExhSector.  This is a HORRIBLE way to use a getter and I doubt its what you really want to do.

Comment: @Jason how should I do it?

Comment: It is not a problem in matter of fact in this way to skip a lot of unneccessery work but this i a different problem. You should focus on two things: 1. What is the DaataContext and is it set properrly 2. When the ExtendedExhibitor.categories is filled? Maybe it is filled after the binding and you should use NotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: @AzzyElvul there is no DataContext, do I need it?
`ExtendedExhibitor.categories` is filled in `DetailPage.xaml.cs`, in the override of OnAppearing() method.

Comment: Because nor I or anybody else here know the structure of your project noone can help you than yourself. So the check the point 1 look at tbe output window and search for a binding errors. About the second point - put a BP on the getters  opening breket and one BP when the ExtendedExhibitor.categories are filled.

Comment: @AzzyElvul the get opening bracket is not reached by program while debugging.

Comment: @AzzyElvul there are no errors displaying on the output window.

Comment: In this case you missed to set the DataContext=

Comment: @AzzyElvul are you referring to BindingContext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, You want to achieve two main function

- **Binding property xml to code.**
- **Value Converters**:If `ExtExhSector` is null or empty, `StackLayout` will be setted to inVisible.

First of all, we achieve **Binding property xml to code**.

1.Create a module `ExtendedExhibitor`.

```
public class ExtendedExhibitor
{
  //  string[] categories;you can add any more attributes
    public string[] categories { get; set; }
}
```

2.Create viewModule `DetailPageViewModel`,I notice you used `ExtExhSector` directly, so `ExtExhSector` cannot be initialized, you will get the null value.

```
   public class DetailPageViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    string extExhSector;
    private ExtendedExhibitor extendedExhibitor;

    public DetailPageViewModel(ExtendedExhibitor extendedExhibitor)
    {
        this.extendedExhibitor = extendedExhibitor;
    }

    public string ExtExhSector
    {
        get
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < extendedExhibitor.categories.Length; i++)
                extExhSector += extendedExhibitor.categories[i].ToString(); ;
            return extExhSector;
        }
        set
        {
            extExhSector = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new 
         PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ExtExhSector)));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

3.Create `xaml` layout.

```
 <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" IsVisible="{Binding ExtExhSector, Converter= 
 {StaticResource nullToVisibilityConverter}}">
    <Label Text="Settore: " TextColor="Blue"/>
    <Label Text="{Binding ExtExhSector}"/>
 </StackLayout>
```

4.Initializing the module and binding the view module to the xml.

```
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
   {
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        var extendedExhibitor=new ExtendedExhibitor();
        string[] test = {"abc","def","hij","k" };
       // string[] test = { };
        extendedExhibitor.categories = test;

        BindingContext = new DetailPageViewModel(extendedExhibitor);
    }
}
```

Then, we achieved **value converter**.

1.Create a converter class and add the logic you want to handle in the converter

```
  public class StringNullOrEmptyBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {


            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty($"{value}");


    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

2. Add the converter to your XAML.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GirdViewDemo"
             x:Class="GirdViewDemo.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:StringNullOrEmptyBoolConverter x:Key="nullToVisibilityConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
  
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" IsVisible="{Binding ExtExhSector, Converter={StaticResource nullToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <Label Text="Settore: " TextColor="Blue"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding ExtExhSector}"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

There is running screenshot.

[image]

If you do not familiar with value converter, you could refer to this link.

https://xamgirl.com/understanding-converters-in-xamarin-forms/

There is my demo

https://github.com/851265601/DataBindingAndValueConverter